# Wrap content property for relative layout in xaml - Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, android-relativelayout, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin forms. How can I set the 'RelativeLayout' content as 'Wrap_Content'. Its possible in Xamarin.Android but not in xamarin.Forms. I have checked 'HorizontalOptions' but its not helpful.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to implement something similar to wrap_content in X.F RelativeLayout. Even though these elements have same name they are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

You might try wrapping your Layout in a parent Layout, that fixed my issue.